# How can I reference another app in container?

Tags: spring, docker-compose, thymeleaf, api-gateway

I have a docker compose with two applications:

1. app1 -spring boot web application with thymeleaf server pages.
2. app2 - another web application with 8080 port exposed.
   I need to be able to address to app2 from ui of app1, like:

```
<a th:href="@{/app2/users}">Users</a>
```

But it's obvious that ui can't make redirection according to container alias.

Also the port is missing, so it needs to be configured.

Perhaps a reverse proxy can be used in that case, but looks like it can be solved much simpler. Is there any Spring component that can be used for routing or a gateway?

Comment: It's unclear what you want Thymeleaf to accomplish here... Like if both apps are on the same server you can use a [server relative url](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#server-relative-urls) -- but if Thymeleaf doesn't know anything about the second app, not sure how you want it to generate a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

The resolved url of /app2 is http(s)://app1/app2 (depending on whether you have SSL configured), which isn't what you want.

Try an absolute url: http(s)://app2:8080/users. I'm not sure what `th:href` does, as I'm not familiar with thymeleaf, but if it doesn't work, just us plain html: `<a href="http://app2:8080/users">Users</a>`